# How to enable WinRM remotely?

Tags: powershell

I am running one of my powershell script on remote machine and I got below error.

> [server1.cn.oim.com] Connecting to remote server server1.cn.oim.com failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the 
>   destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the 
>   following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig".

I am calling all host name in $server and is there any powershell script so that WinRM can be enabled remotely ?

Comment: You can't use PowerShell remoting to enable PowerShell remoting. :-)  You could try `psexec` or WMI with `Win32_Process` etc. to create a process that runs the command

Comment: If they are domain joined you can do it with [Group Policy](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2014/05/enable-winrm-via-group-policy/)

Comment: ok, thanks for the information

Comment: I have used a command like below to enable winrm .but its not working well. Please help .Here $servername is already collecting servername in my script                                                                                           $command = "winrm quickconfig -force"
$cmd = "CMD.EXE /c "+$command

Invoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_process -name Create -ArgumentList $cmd -ComputerName "$servername"